# Get full image from UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a UIImagePickerController and every time i select an image i get the cropped version of the image, i want the full image, how can i do this?

```
- (void)tapSelectAd:(id)sender
{

picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
picker.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:picker.sourceType];
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;


[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

 }




- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *) Picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
UIImage *image=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
selectedImage.image = image;
}
```

Comment: 1) Update your question with the code that gets the selected image. 2) If you always want the original image, why do you allow editing?

Comment: @rmaddy, when i don't use that i can't see the image being selected

Comment: If you want the full image, don't ask for the edited image. Use `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage`.

Answer (score 4):

Try this: You need to set allowsEditing to NO and use UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage when you pick your image.

```
- (void)tapSelectAd:(id)sender
{
    picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    picker.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:picker.sourceType];
    picker.allowsEditing = NO;
    picker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *) Picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    UIImage *image=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    selectedImage.image = image;
}
```